# Google Playstore

Tags: google-play-store

When I enter my playstore it asks for existing account I put it in and it says that I need to have a better connection would sit right next to my router and same thing please help

Comment: Did you try a better connection?

Comment: Yeah still dosent work

Comment: Modify the question title to get more views. And just go through Play Store related questions too.

Comment: Did you accidentally erase `com.android.Google.gsf.login` or similar? Have you wiped dalvik-cache and cache in recovery? Did you try deleting data and cache for Play Store and Play Services in applications? Please edit your question with further details (ROM, rooted/not, what steps you tried, things you may have deleted, and anything else useful) and edit your question title.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do a factory reset after all that's what Google customer service told me to do after the same problem happened to me. It should work fine after that though.

Comment: That's one example, but on the extreme side. You also don't mention to make a backup at all.